# Can I multiply fractions in map algebra?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, raster-calculator, map-algebra

I have a couple of rasters that show % of success in different things. I want to calculate the overall probability of success. The numerical values are integers so they represent the percentage. This means that my calulation should be:

```
newRaster = (Raster("t35_sealrisk2")/100) * (Raster("t34_res_risk4")/100)
```

The problem is that this produces only 0 or 1. I have also tried outputting one of the rasters divided by 100 and it is also 0 or 100. It seems that at no stage in the calculation does it handle the numbers as franctions - if I multiply everything by 100 I still only get 0 and 100.

If this a problem with map algebra that it cannot handle fractions, or is it because my inputs are integers it will consider everything as an integer?

Comment: My first guess would be that this is an integer-related problem, where you divide an integer with an integer with only integers as result. Try to divide by 100.0 instead, which gives probably an integer-by-float division with a float as a result.

Comment: Just use float (raster)/100 etc

Comment: @chkaiser you're absolutely right. Adding the .0 works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The / operator in Python 2.x does integer division. See the help on the [Divide](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/divide.htm) tool more information.  Lots of ways to fix it:

```
risk2 = Raster("t35_sealrisk2")
risk4 = Raster("t34_res_risk4")
newRaster = (risk2 / 100.) * (risk4) / 100.)
newRaster = risk2 * risk4 * .01
newRaster = Int((risk2 * risk4 * .01) + 0.5) # round to integer percent
```